# Text based Java game wont reset properly

Tags: java, text-based

the problem I'm currently facing is that I try to restart the game after you fail/die.
In the beginning of the game it asks you for your name, upon entering it you get a "good morning, name" message and are sent to the next class which is waking up in your room.
It works at first but when I restart the game, it immediately says "good morning, !" and goes to the room class.
I understand that this is some problem with the name variable, but I don't understand what exactly I'm doing wrong..
This is my first question posted, I hope it is not too messy.

Here is my "preparation" class, which is just asking for the name, saying good morning, and then moving to the next class.

```
public void Preparation() {
        String playerName;
        System.out.println("Please enter your name:");
        playerName = scn.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nGood morning, " + playerName + "!");
        YourRoom();
    }
```

This is the YourRoom class.

```
public void YourRoom() {
        System.out.println("\nYou wake up early, what do you want to do first?");
        System.out.println("1: Sleep in");
        System.out.println("2: Wake up");
```

And here is an example of a fail/death in a further class.

```
System.out.println("choice 1 : enter deadly choice here");
        choice = scn.nextInt();
        if (choice == 1) {
            Points = 0;
            System.out.println("You have died, please enter something to restart");
            enterScanner.nextLine();
            Preparation();
            }
```

However, after entering something to restart the console displays this:

Please enter your name:

Good morning, !

You wake up early, what do you want to do first?
1: Sleep in
2: Wake up

Comment: It's most likely linked to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

Comment: So the problem may be the scn.nextInt when getting the users choice? The "enterScanner.nextLine();" after dying is not skipped.. it's just the one after that. Are you saying I should try getting the users choice as a String and then converting it? @Stultuske

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code around. Is enterScanner the same scanner as scn? Btw. theres a stackoverflow if someone plays too many rounds. It would be better to create a loop at the beginning which calls Preparation or YourRoom from the same level instead of calling it from itself over and over again.

Comment: @Jens I have fixed the name problem, the link posted by Stultuske explained why it skipped my scanner. But yes enterScanner and scn are the same. I don't understand what you mean by the last sentence, though. I'm very new to programming and this was only a small exercise for myself.